# Swiping a ViewGroup, not a View and removing it

Tags: android

I would like to make a **vertical swipeable ViewGroup**.
[Thanks to Roman Nurik, i have found something very useful on Lars Vogel's site.](http://www.vogella.com/code/com.vogella.android.list.swipetodismiss/src/com/vogella/android/listview/swipetodismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.html)

Basicly this is a **horizontall swipeDismissTouchListener** which is working verry correctly on Views, **but only and exactly with Views, not ViewGroups.**

With this class you can add a TouchListener to a View so you can swipe it left and right. 
If you swipe it far left or right, it will be dismissed.

**I modified this code to get the horizontall working**, so now you can swipe the specific View to Up and Down.

I was very happy... **Until i found out it is not working on ViewGroups.**

First of all i see that the class i use **is implementing** `View.OnTouchListener`, but there is no such thing in ViewGroup ... :-\

My ViewGroup is an extended LinearLayout with many added Views, so i really need this work with ViewGroups and not simple Views.

[image]

Please advice me something, or tell me what should i modify in the code to get it work with ViewGroups.

**E D I T:**

I went for some logging while i waiting for good suggestions and i just realized that

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
```

in

```
onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
```

does not run while i try to swipe a ViewGroup but does run with Views... why?

**(Actual code is in the link in the begining of the question)**

Comment: a ViewGroup is a subClass of View. So those methods that are available for view are available for view groups. If I understood your question correctly

Comment: Yes you are, but then why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your first view is the one "Swipeable", my question is, why not use a ScrollView? it is like a FrameLayout (put anything you want in it, via XML or programmatically) but it is scrollable and it has no size restrictions. Or a ListView? I mean, you should use one thing or another depending on how you add these Views to your Layout.

IMHO if these elements don't change over time or you need to refresh the Activity to change them use a ListView, if you need to put Layouts dynamically use a ScrollView (it seems to be the best aproach to what you're trying).

Hope it helped you out.

Comment: No scrollview and listview is for a different purpose.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get it in the first place, sorry. I think there is a way to handle touch events for viewgroups here http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html hope it helps you to solve your problem ;)